# Autoconfiguration of ActiveMQ with spring integration

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-integration, spring-boot, spring-jms

In current versions spring boot can also configure a ConnectionFactory when it detects that ActiveMQ is available on the classpath. If the broker is present, an embedded broker is started and configured automatically.

This seems to be true when using the JMSTemplate. If I want to use spring integration auto configuration then unfortunately this does not work. ActiveMQ seems to be configured AFTER spring integration. Spring boot reports error for missing connection factory. 
I am using spring boot version 1.1.4 and most current version of spring integration for this.

I get this stacktrace from spring boot:

```
2014-08-08 09:24:21.050 ERROR 6728 --- [           main]    
o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsSendingMessageHandler#0': 
Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#54930080' of type 
[org.springframework.integration.jms.DynamicJmsTemplate] while setting constructor 
argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#54930080': Cannot resolve reference to 
bean 'connectionFactory' while setting bean property 'connectionFactory'; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean 
named 'connectionFactory' is defined
at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(
BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:290)
at   
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.
resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
```

For me it seems that the dependencies in spring boot auto configurations are not correct with respect of spring integration and jms template.
Standard JMS auto configuration looks like the following:

```
@ConditionalOnClass(JmsTemplate.class)
@ConditionalOnBean(ConnectionFactory.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(JmsProperties.class)
@AutoConfigureAfter({ HornetQAutoConfiguration.class, 
ActiveMQAutoConfiguration.class })
public class JmsAutoConfiguration
```

Spring integration looks like the following:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(EnableIntegration.class)
@AutoConfigureAfter(JmxAutoConfiguration.class)
public class IntegrationAutoConfiguration {
```

Shouldn't there be at least some kind of auto configuration for the dynamic jms template that spring integration creates regarding connection factory and active mq. Considering the spring boot ref docs I would expect correct auto configuration with jms for spring integration as well?

Comment: Please describe further - much more than "does not work"; include configuration, stack traces etc. I suggest you take a DEBUG log; if you can't figure it out from the log, post it somewhere and I am sure someone will help.

Comment: Such cases is the reason you would want to wire up the components manually - to control "depends-on" and startup order. I have no answer to the problem though.

Comment: What auto configuration are you talking about exactly?

Comment: I added some more detail to my question, hopefully it gets clearer what my issue is. I can solve this defining an connection factory bean manually but then spring boot should mention this in the ref docs that for spring integration the jms auto configuration together with active mq auto configuration does not work

Comment: I am not sure to understand what JMX has to do with that. Can you post a project somewhere that reproduces the problem?

Comment: It has nothing to do with jmx. It is about jms and spring integration auto configuration. In my opinion there is something missing in class IntegrationAutoConfiguration regarding jms connection factory with Activemq or Hornetq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - got it.  It's a bug (I think).

[ActiveMQConnectionFactoryConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.5.x/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactoryConfiguration.java) creates a bean called "jmsConnectionFactory" but looking at your stacktrace (above) Spring Integration is looking for the bean to be named: 'connectionFactory'

**Edit:** [INT-3941](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3941) opened

**Workaround:**

```
@Configuration
public static class SpringBootVsIntegraionWorkaround {
    @Autowired
    GenericApplicationContext genericApplicationContext;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        genericApplicationContext.registerAlias("jmsConnectionFactory", "connectionFactory");
    }
}
```

Comment: ActiveMQConnectionFactoryConfiguration link is dead now.

Comment: Thanks.  The structure changed in 2.0.  I've updated the link to point to the 1.5  branch (where I found it) rather than master.

Answer (score 0):

I've replicated this issue.  Here's an example:

Before (just to show everything works):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloWorldSiActivemqApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldSiActivemqApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Service
    public static class SayHelloService {
        @Autowired
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

        public void sayHello(String name){
            System.out.println("JMS Connection Factory: " + connectionFactory);
            System.out.println("##  Hello " + name + "!!!" );
        }
    }

    @Component
    public static class HelloListener {
        @Autowired
        SayHelloService sayHelloService;

        @JmsListener(destination="helloJMSQueue")
        public void sayHello(String name){
            sayHelloService.sayHello(name);
        }
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://0.0.0.0:61613
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=password
```

That works just fine.  When I hit the JMS endpoint with a unit test I get:

```
JMS Connection Factory: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory@4b137f92
##  Hello SayHelloServiceTest!!!
```

However, when I introduce Spring Integration:

```
@ImportResource("classpath*:/spring/si-config.xml")
```

si-config.xml

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="helloJMSAdapater" destination="helloJMSQueue"
        channel="helloChannel"/>

<integration:channel id="helloChannel"/>
```

..and re-run my test I get:

```
No bean named 'connectionFactory' is defined
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When an 'connectionFactory' bean is automatically set up a simple workaround is to use an alias to have both available:

```
    <alias name="connectionFactory" alias="jmsConnectionFactory" />
```